# How do I setup PageRules to bypass Caching against an entire image directory?

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I'm working with Cloudflare and one of its benefits is caching.  There are certain areas of my site that shouldn't be cached as the results need to be seen by the user.  I run an online store and images for products are stored in directories which are also designated by the product Id, this means there are quite a few directories and I don't want the images to be cached.

Here are a few example URLs of product images on my website.

```
www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/87/image300.jpg
www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/88/image300.jpg
www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/94/image300.jpg
www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/27/image300.jpg
```

To get around the caching of the above directories I tried adding page rules within the Cloudflare dashboard, despite my best efforts I cannot get Cloudflare to stop caching all the images within the `products` directory.

My first attempt was to use a wildcard and prevent caching across all pages on my site, the pagerule I used was:

```
mysite.co.uk/*
```

However, the above rule didn't seem to do anything.  I then attempt to get more granular with it and opted for a rule like this:

```
mysite.co.uk/images/products/*
```

This rule didn't seem to work either.  I then looked at more advanced wildcard use but I fear I got out of my depth:

```
mysite.co.uk/images/products/*/$1.jpg
```

Needless to say, the above rule didn't work either.  So, my question is, what rule should I use to prevent caching of my product images?

Comment: What is your "Browser Cache TTL" setting? From my understanding, without "Respect existing headers" your images will be cached.

Comment: Also, the page rules you posted don't match the URLs you gave because the subdomain, either use www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/* or \*mysite.co.uk/images/products/\*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is published at `www.mysite.co.uk` and the images you don't want to cache are under `www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/...` then, you would create a page rule such as:

[image: Cloudflare Bypass Cache Rule]

This rule will tell Cloudflare to not store the resources matching the expression on the CDN. You can also change the rule to match `www.mysite.co.uk/images/products/*.jpg` if you only want to match `jpg` images under that folder.

Finally: if there are more page rules defines, it is recommended ordering them from most to least specific, as [only one rule is matched for every request](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-#h_7rzfw5kI8cqu4VKur6Mnur).

Comment: This worked for a bit and then it started caching the images again.